# How can I add "Id" to every row in my table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I have a table loaded with Ajax data (call shown below):

```
 success: function (data) {
        var aRC = JSON.parse(data.d);
        var line = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < aRC.length; i++) {
            var id = aRC[i].Id;
            var num = id;
            var rev = aRC[i].field;

            lines += '<tr id="V' + num + '" data-id="' + num + '">';
            lines += '<td>' + num + '</td>';
            lines += '<td id="V' + num + '-1">' + rev + '</td>';
            lines += '<td class="text-center">';
            lines += '   <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="' + num + '"></span>';
            lines += '   <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="' + num + '"></span>';
            lines += ' </td>';
            lines += '</tr>';
        }
        $('#TableVS').html(lines);
```

This is what my page looks like after the Ajax call:

[image: Result]

When I click on the edit span the input Value Stream is automatically filled with row data, and when I click on the remove span DataTables prompts me with a pop-up to confirm removal of the row. My issue stems from trying to load the row ID when I click on the edit/delete spans.

**The Problem**

The data is correctly loaded to my DataTable, but the issue is that when I click on the spans, nothing happens. I believe that this is because I'm not assigning the Id for each row and I want to know how to do so?

Here is the my code for loading the data from the input

```
function editarDatosVs(id) {
    if ($('#V' + id).length) {
        var id = $('#V' + id).attr('data-id');

        $('#IdVs').val(id);
        var rev = $('#V' + id + '-1').html();

        $('#vs').val(rev);

    }
    else {
        $('#IdVs').val('0');
        $('#vs').val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this? It's often simpler and easier to just access the rows by index using `eq()`, instead of doing a mass of DOM updates which may not be required.

Comment: Agree with Rory, easier to navigate internally.  That said, I doubt your binding is correct which is why nothing happens when you click the button.  You need to use the overload for .on() when you create html dynamically. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Because I have another functions that requires the specif Id, when I click on the edit buton I store the Id into a hidden input so then I can use it, and with the delete button I have to send the Id number to execute the function.

Comment: These functions that require the specific rowId; are you referring to the default DataTables edit/delete functions or have you written custom functions?

Comment: Are custom functions, example: when I click on delete I do this var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); and the execute the function delete(id) wich is an ajax call where I send the parameter Id to execute a sql query, delete from where Id=@id thats what I need the specific id, all works but I want to to this with jquery DataTables

Answer (score 0):

Given a table with a similar structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="id"/>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="1"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="1"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="2"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="2"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="3"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="3"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="4"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="4"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="5"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="5"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="6"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="6"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="7"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="7"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="8"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="8"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="9"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="9"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="10"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="10"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="11"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="11"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="12"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="12"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="13"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="13"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="14"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="14"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="15"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="15"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="16"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="16"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="17"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="17"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="18"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="18"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="19"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="19"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="20"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="20"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="21"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="21"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="22"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="22"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="23"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="23"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="24"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="24"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="25"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="25"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>26</td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="26"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="26"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="27"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="27"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="28"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="28"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="29"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="29"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="30"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="30"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="31"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="31"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="32"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="32"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="33"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="33"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="34"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="34"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="35"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="35"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="36"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="36"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="37"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="37"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="38"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="38"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="39"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="39"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="40"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="40"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="41"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="41"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="42"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="42"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="43"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="43"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="44"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="44"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="45"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="45"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="46"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="46"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="47"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="47"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="48"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="48"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="49"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="49"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="50"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="50"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="51"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="51"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="52"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="52"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="53"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="53"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="54"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="54"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="55"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="55"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="56"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="56"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>57</td>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="57"></span>
                    <span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-id="57"></span>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This code seems to do what you want:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
});

$('#example').on("click", ".glyphicon-remove", function(){
    $("#id").val($(this).data("id"));
});
```

If I've misunderstood your requirements do say but I think that that is what you're after? Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/wagg9b94/).

Answer (score 0):

add sClass index to the id column

```
var updateIndex = function(){
        $( this ).find('tr').each(function(){
            $( this ).find( "td.index" ).html( $(this).index()+1);
        });
    };

updateIndex.call(Table);//table is the datatable reference
```

call this after insertion or deletion of rows

Answer (score 0):

Adding to  what Rory said, call the function in rowcallback in the datatable setup and extend this function.Then set the datatable back to your datatable div.